# Modifying screen swiping functionality for use in a slider (iOS7)

Tags: ios, ios7

I am interested in trying to modify the functionality that allows full-screen swiping from one view to another in order to create a "slider" that is the size of the entire page -- i.e. dragging/swiping/sliding anywhere on the page has an effect of some kind.

It doesn't need to be visible. For example, I might have a solid red screen that I can change the colour of by dragging to the right anywhere, having it gradually change to blue.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible.

Comment: Any suggestion as to how to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a UIPanGestureRecognizer, you can track finger movement on the screen, then use translationInView to find out how much the user's finger moved by, and change the color somehow based on that number

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

And handle it:

```
-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    CGFloat xMovement = [sender translationInView:sender.view].x;
    // Do something with the movement

    // Then reset the translation
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:sender.view];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind explaining how the direction is handled? e.g. if I want to recognize that a finger is being dragged to the left

Comment: if xMovement is positive it means you are moving to the right, negative moves to the left. Same for Y direction, negative is up, positive is down